# Multiple FancyBox not closing even after calling close method

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, fancybox

I am using multiple jquery FancyBox instance on a single page. Upon calling

> jquery.fancybox.close()

it is not closing it at all

Script generating FancyBox given below:

```
<script>
                    $("#firstTimeIntro").fancybox(
                        {
                        maxWidth    : "30%",
                        maxHeight   : "50%",
                        fitToView   : false,
                        width       : '70%',
                        height      : '70%',
                        autoSize    : false,
                        closeClick  : false,
                        openEffect  : 'none',
                        closeEffect : 'none'
                        }
                    ).trigger('click');
                     $.fancybox.update();
                </script>
```

This is how I am closing fancybox:

```
$("#notRightnow").click(function(e) 
    {
      //$.cookie('navafiz_notrightnow', '1', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
       $.fancybox.close();
    });
```

In order to test in real environment visit [here](http://clients.sidlabs.com/navafiz/main.php).

On page Load it will show a popup to ask you to sign In. When you click **Not Right now** link it should close popUp but it is not.

Comment: Don't ask people to login into your site but post your complete code instead including the html involved.

Comment: Code Updated. Please see  now

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I sorted this out. The best way to deal with multiple fancyboxes is to declared a class, forinstance `fancybox` to the link that will load popup and trigger click. Code is given below:

**HTML**

```
  <div style="display:none;"  id="firstTimeIntro">
            Loading First Time Intro
            <a id="closeme" href="#">Close Me</a>
        </div>
        <a class="fancybox" href="#firstTimeIntro" id="hiddenIntroBox" style="display: block">Hidden</a>
        <div style="display:none;"  id="firstTimeIntro1">
            Loading First Time Intro 2nd time
            <a id="closeme1" href="#">Close Me</a>
        </div>
        <a class="fancybox" href="#firstTimeIntro1" id="hiddenIntroBox1" style="display: block">Hidden</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                maxWidth    : "70%",
        maxHeight   : "70%",
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
    $.fancybox.update();
    //$("#hiddenIntroBox").trigger('click');
    $("#hiddenIntroBox1").trigger('click');
    $("#closeme").click(function(e) 
    {
      //$.cookie('navafiz_notrightnow', '1', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
       $.fancybox.close();
    });
    $("#closeme1").click(function(e) 
    {
      //$.cookie('navafiz_notrightnow', '1', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
       $.fancybox.close();
    });
}
);
```